# How to download a file and stream it immidiately - upload - using Spring Reactive WebClient

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I'm looking into a way to download a file from a url and immediately stream it (upload) it to another url (location). I don't want to dump it into disk or download the whole file in memory.

I'm new to Spring Reactive API. I came up with something like this in Kotlin:

```kotlin
val buff = WebClient.create("downloadUrl").get().retrieve().bodyToFlux(DataBuffer::class.java)

WebClient.create("uploadUrl").post().body(buff)
```

`body` above is `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.body`

But I'm not sure if I'm even on the right path. What is the right way of doing it?

Comment: Answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69782155/2659499)