# Cannot upload a file using WebClient when its content ( Flux<DataBuffer>) is wrapped in another object

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

Spring boot: 2.5.6, Kotlin: 1.5.31, kotlinx-coroutines-reactive:1.5.2

I'm trying to download a pdf and immidiately upload it to `http://localhost:3000/upload` as below:

```kotlin
Class Mediator(val dataBuffer: Flux<DataBuffer>, val url: String)

runBlocking {
  getMediator()
    .flatMap { uploadFile(it) }
    .subscribe()
}

  private fun getMediator(): Mono<Mediator> {
    return WebClient.create(
            "https://server.com/assets/file.pdf")
        .get()
        .exchangeToMono { response ->
          Mono.just(
              Mediator(response.bodyToFlux(DataBuffer::class.java), "http://localhost:3000/upload"))
        }
  }
  private fun uploadFile(mediator: Mediator): Mono<ResponseEntity<Void>> {
    return WebClient.create(mediator.url)
        .put()
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
        .body(mediator.dataBuffer)
        .retrieve()
        .toBodilessEntity()
  }
```

When I run this code I can see that my server receives a call and creates an empty file (0 size). No error is raised. I cannot explain why this code does not transfer bytes to my upload endpoint. While testing I realized that the issue might be in my `Mediator` object that `getMediator` is returning. Somehow `body` in `uploadFile` does not Like a wrapped `Flux<DataBuffer>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do this. Just answering my own question in case this might help others.

```kotlin
data class Mediator(val data: Flux<DataBuffer>, val url: String)
data class UploadUrl(val url: String)

runBlocking {
  getFileDataBuffer(url)
     .flatMap { prepareUpload(it.headers.contentLength, it.body) }
     .flatMap { uploadFile(it.url, it.dataBuffer!!)}
}.subscribe()

private fun getFileDataBuffer(url:String): Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<DataBuffer>>> {
  return WebClient.create(url).get().retrieve().toEntityFlux()
}

private fun prepareUpload(length: Long, data: Flux<DataBuffer>?): Mono<Mediator> {
    return WebClient.create("http://localhost:3000/prepare")
        .post()
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .bodyValue("""{"size":${length}}""")
        .exchangeToMono { res ->
          res.bodyToMono(String::class.java).map { parseJson<UploadUrl>(it) }.map {
            Mediator(data, it.url)
          }
        }
  }

private fun uploadFile(url: String, data: Flux<DataBuffer>): Mono<ResponseEntity<Void>> {
    return WebClient.create(url)
        .put()
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
        .body(data)
        .retrieve()
        .toBodilessEntity()
  }
```